# why this query added extra length upper(trim(LEFT(col_name::varchar, 100)))

Tags: sql, vertica

```
select
    distinct upper(trim(LEFT(col_name::varchar, 100))) as col_name from mytable;
```

Somehow this added extra length since LEFT(col_name::varchar, 100) returns 100 character from left.

And I am getting below error when inserting to another table

> ERROR: String of 101 octets is too long for type Varchar(100)
> If anyone could help me in understanding this behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [LEFT(string, N)](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/String/LEFT.htm) function returns N **characters** from the left side of a string.

However, those N characters may take more than N bytes ([**octects**](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.3.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/String/OCTET_LENGTH.htm)), for example accented characters:

```
dbadmin=> select left('é', 1);
 left
------
 é

dbadmin=> select octet_length(left('é', 1));
 octet_length
--------------
            2
```